# Java How to calculate the average of 3 bowling scores

Tags: java, while-loop, average

I'm writing a program that calculates and displays the average bowling scores of each bowler the user inputs. 
I'm having trouble calculating the average of the 3 scores, right now I think it's calculating the total of the the scores. How do I make it so it calculates the average of the scores

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{



//local constants


  //local variables
    String bowler = "";
    int total = 0;
    int average = 0;
    int score1 = 0;
    int score2 = 0;
    int score3 = 0;

  /********************   Start main method  *****************/

  //Enter in the name of the first bowler
  System.out.print(setLeft(40," Input First Bowler or stop to Quit: "));
  bowler = Keyboard.readString();

  //Enter While loop if input isn't q
  while(!bowler.equals("stop"))
  {

      System.out.print(setLeft(40," 1st Bowling Score:"));
      score1 = Keyboard.readInt();
      System.out.print(setLeft(40," 2nd Bowling Score:"));
      score2 = Keyboard.readInt();
      System.out.print(setLeft(40," 3rd Bowling Score:"));
      score3 = Keyboard.readInt();
      if(score1 >= 0 && score1 <= 300 && score2 >= 0 && score2 <= 300 && score3 >= 0 && score3 <= 300)
      {
          total += score1;
          total += score2;
          total += score3;
          System.out.println(setLeft(41,"Total: ")+ total);
          average = score1 + score2 + score3 / 3;
          System.out.println(setLeft(41,"Average: ") + average);


      }
      else
      {
          System.out.println(setLeft(40,"Error"));

      }
```

Comment: What input and output are you getting as of now for the average?

Comment: If i input 20 for every score it says the average is 46, not sure why

Comment: Tip: Sprinkle parentheses liberally on your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java's mathematical operators obey the standard mathematical precedence, so it's

```
   int average = score1 + score2 + (score3 / 3);
```

However, your intention was likely

```
   int average = (score1 + score2 + score3) / 3;
```

Finally you most likely want to do this calculation in `double` (or `float`) arithmetic, otherwise it will be rounded down

```
double average = (double)(score1 + score2 + score3) / 3;
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the integer division, although the question does also have `average` as `int`, and so that should also probably be `double`

Answer (score 3):

The division (`/`) operator has a higher precedence than the addition operator (`+`), so you need to enclose the sum with brackets before dividing:

```
average = (score1 + score2 + score3) / 3;
// Here --^------------------------^
```